# What's the exact type of lock PostgreSQL acquires when performing an `UPDATE`?

Tags: postgresql, locking

I'm aware that programmers have the option to acquire [explicit locks](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/explicit-locking.html) when performing database operations, but I'd like more clarity into what type of lock Postgres acquires (automatically) when performing common operations, such as `UPDATE`.

Comment: Could you clarify what the documentation insufficiently explains (i.e., what is unclear in the documentation)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, let's look and see.

First, open two connections. In the first one (fill in the table, etc, with values appropriate to your DB):

```
=# BEGIN;
=# UPDATE table SET field = x WHERE id = y;
```

Now, switch to the other connection. Use `pg_stat_activity` to find the `pid` for the other connection:

```
=# SELECT pid FROM pg_stat_activity WHERE query = 'UPDATE table SET field = x WHERE id = y;';

 pid
------
 1684
(1 row)
```

Obviously, the `pid` (process id) will vary.

Alright, now use that `pid` to find out the locks that are in play:

```
=# SELECT * FROM pg_locks WHERE pid = 1684;
   locktype    | database | relation |  page  | tuple  | virtualxid | transactionid | classid | objid  | objsubid | virtualtransaction | pid |       mode       | granted | fastpath 
---------------+----------+----------+--------+--------+------------+---------------+---------+--------+----------+--------------------+-----+------------------+---------+----------
 relation      |    16384 |    16385 | [null] | [null] | [null]     |        [null] |  [null] | [null] |   [null] | 4/10730            | 743 | RowExclusiveLock | t       | t
 virtualxid    |   [null] |   [null] | [null] | [null] | 4/10730    |        [null] |  [null] | [null] |   [null] | 4/10730            | 743 | ExclusiveLock    | t       | t
 transactionid |   [null] |   [null] | [null] | [null] | [null]     |          1440 |  [null] | [null] |   [null] | 4/10730            | 743 | ExclusiveLock    | t       | f
(3 rows)
```

Now, both `ExclusiveLock`s are on the transaction and virtual transaction. We can ignore those -- they'll be around for pretty much every transaction, regardless of what it's doing.

But the `RowExclusiveLock` has a database and relation associated with it. The relation is the table you're updating.

So the proper answer to your question is a `RowExclusiveLock`.

Now you can `ROLLBACK` or `COMMIT` your update transaction and clean up. If you want to know the lock types used when you `SELECT FOR UPDATE`, you can follow the same procedure.

Note that this is the simplest case: updating one row of one table. More complicated updates are likely to have more locks associated with them.